# Discrepancy between df -h and ll -h returned information

Tags: linux, shell, rhel

everyone!
`df -h` shows that a disk is full (used 100%).
But when I use `ll -h`total size of files almost 2%.
Can someone explain what happens?

Comment: check temporary files

Comment: @meowmeow : What is `ll`?

Comment: @user1934428 alias for `ls -l`

Comment: In this case, `df` and `ll` are completely unrelated. `df` tells you something about how much of the file space on your hard disk is used. `ls -l` doesn't tell you anything about this. It just gives a total for the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main reasons for that:

1. In Linux, you can delete a file even when it is opened by someone else (some program, for example). This is because, when you delete a file, only filesystem reference to this file is removed, the actual file itself is removed (and disk space is freed) only when all the users have closed this file. `ls` cannot see files that are deleted but still in use.
2. Almost all filesystems arrange their data in blocks, usually 4Kbytes. That means, when you create a small file, the actual disk space used is still at least 4K. When you have a lot of small files, then this becomes significant.

Difference between `ls` and `df` comes from the fact, that one displays the size of the file contents while the other shows the actual disk space used.

Comment: Thanks,  I got it! Great answer.